# PHP Login issue when checking hashed/salted password

Tags: php, hash, passwords, salt, account

My checkPassword() method returns false every time even though I know it is right. I used the same method for hashing/salting as I did for checking and I made sure everything is the way it should be but it still returns false.
I'm using 'Bcrypt-PHP-Class' found here to hash everything https://github.com/cosenary/Bcrypt-PHP-Class
Here is how I hashed the password:

```
$password = Bcrypt::hashPassword($_POST['password']);
```

Here is how I check the password:

```
$check = Bcrypt::checkPassword($password, $user['password']);
```

($user is an array of the user's information like username,password,email etc.)
$check is still false even after checking that everything is exactly right. There are no errors either.
Thanks in advanced to anyone who can help me out.
Bcrypt methods:

```
public static function checkPassword($password, $storedHash) {
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3') < 0) {
  throw new Exception('Bcrypt requires PHP 5.3 or above');
}

self::_validateIdentifier($storedHash);
$checkHash = crypt($password, $storedHash);

return ($checkHash === $storedHash);
}
public static function hashPassword($password, $workFactor = 0) {
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3') < 0) {
  throw new Exception('Bcrypt requires PHP 5.3 or above');
}

$salt = self::_genSalt($workFactor);
return crypt($password, $salt);
}
```

Comment: can you post the functions as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't use password_hash() ? (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.password-hash.php)

And look into your DB if the password field is a varchar and minimum 60 characters (for password_hash, don't know for Bcrypt-PHP-class)

EDIT :
Bcrypt-PHP-Class create a 60 chars hash, check if your fields have this minimum